# Vertical alignment in matrix alignment with cylinder

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

In the following MWE, the nodes in the matrix are not properly vertically aligned:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=6mm,level distance=1.3cm,every node/.style={inner sep=4pt, text depth=0pt, minimum width=24mm,minimum height=24mm,align=center,inner sep=2pt}]

    \matrix [draw=red] {
    \node[draw=black, rectangle] {A}; & \node[draw=black,cylinder,shape border rotate=90,shape aspect=.25] {B\\ C\\ D}; & \node[draw=black,cylinder,shape border rotate=90,shape aspect=.25] {Bbbbbbbb\\ Cccccccc\\ Dddddddd};\\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It seems that the problem is introduced by the `cylinder` shape since the second cylinder is aligned worse than the second.

By the way, why is the `cylinder`'s aspect dependent on the text it contains?

Comment: By default `matrix nodes` are aligned to its center. You can change this alignment with `anchor` option. `\matrix[anchor=south]` will align all nodes to their bottom point.

Comment: I'd also really like to know why the aspect changes based on the node's text, and how I could stop it from changing.  Thoughts?

Comment: @AdamCrume you should probably ask a new question for this, I doubt that people are going to see it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `matrix nodes` are aligned to its `center`. TiKZ offers `anchor` option to change `matrix cells` alignment. If you want to align all nodes to their bottom point, use `\matrix[anchor=south]`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=4pt,% 
       text depth=0pt, minimum width=24mm,%
       minimum height=24mm, align=center, inner sep=2pt}]

    \matrix [draw=red] {
    \node[draw=black, rectangle] (a) {A}; & 
    \node[draw=black,cylinder,shape border rotate=90,shape aspect=.25] (b) {B\\ C\\ D}; 
  & \node[draw=black,cylinder,shape border rotate=90,shape aspect=.25] (c) {Bbbbbbbb\\ 
                    Cccccccc\\ Dddddddd};\\
    };
    \foreach \i in {a,b,c}
        \fill[red] (\i.center) circle(1pt);
    \draw[red] (a.center)--(b.center)--(c.center);

\begin{scope}[yshift=-5cm]

    \matrix [draw=red,anchor=south] {
    \node[draw=black, rectangle] (a) {A}; & 
    \node[draw=black,cylinder,shape border rotate=90,shape aspect=.25] (b) {B\\ C\\ D}; 
  & \node[draw=black,cylinder,shape border rotate=90,shape aspect=.25] (c) {Bbbbbbbb\\ 
                   Cccccccc\\ Dddddddd};\\
    };
    \foreach \i in {a,b,c}{
        \fill[red] (\i.center) circle(1pt);
        \fill[blue] (\i.south) circle(1pt);
    }
    \draw[red] (a.center)--(b.center)--(c.center);
    \draw[blue] (a.south)--(b.south)--(c.south);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]